# How can we make an class that contains multiple uielements and acts as a uielement

Tags: c#, wpf, shapes, uielement

We would like to make a little drawing application and i don't know how to make a class derived from shape or uielement or something else that contains multiple objects like a line and text or multiple lines that are not connected.
How would i do that?

For an ellipse i have this:

```
public class B_Null : Shape
{
    EllipseGeometry eg;
    public double Breedte { get; private set; }

    public B_Null()
    {
        Stroke = Brushes.Red;
        StrokeThickness = 1;
        Fill = Brushes.Red;
        eg = new EllipseGeometry(new Point(100, 100), 100, 100);
        Breedte = 200;
    }

    protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
    {
        get
        {
            return eg;
        }
    }

}
```

The above works but it cannot handle multiple uielements? 
(Or multiple lines that are not connected)

The goal is to have one class that contains multiple elements.
At the end i want to use this code: Canvas.SetTop(MyUiElement,...);

Comment: Why not inherit from Canvas?

Comment: Inheritance from Controls in WPF can be a real pain. A far better (i.e. simpler) option is to create your own UserControl that contains a top-level Grid/Canvas item, and then put your various UI elements inside that.

Comment: You don't need this derived control. Just use an ItemsControl, probably with a Canvas as ItemsPanel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you ver much for the information! I inherited my drawing objects from the Canvas and then add all my objects easily on a canvas.

```
public class B_Null : Canvas
{
    private Ellipse Ellipse = new Ellipse();


    public B_Null()
    {
        Ellipse.Width = 200;
        Ellipse.Height = 200;
        Ellipse.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
        Ellipse.StrokeThickness = 1;
        Ellipse.Fill = Brushes.Red;
        this.Children.Add(Ellipse);
    }



}
```